# MailChimp emails don't arrive at strato.de addresses

Tags: email, mailchimp

I want to use MailChimp for sending a newsletter to a list of people's email addresses (I do have all the permissions). I set up the list correctly and sent out a test mail but it only arrives at mail accounts running on web.de, Hotmail, etc. but not the private email addresses running on strato.de. I texted MailChimp's customer care but they said it probably is STRATO's spam filters. Now, I turned those off for my (standard) account but the emails still don't arrive.

Any idea what may solve this issue?